# Why is the text overlapping in an infinite scroll animation on the X axis?

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to set up an infinite animation effect but the seems to overlap every time I add another row (green banner) and if the div is rotated at an angle. It looks fine if there is only one green banner and if it's straight but I'm not sure why it overlaps when there are multiple. Any help would be appreciated. Image is attached for reference.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section .scroll {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #99e836;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  margin: 8rem 0;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 2px solid white;
}

section .scroll div {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 800;
  animation: animate 40s linear infinite;
}

section .scroll div:nth-child(2) {
  animation: animate2 40s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: -20s;
}

section .scroll div span {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

.transparent {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1.3px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: blue;
  font-weight: 600;
  &-no {
    color: black;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

@keyframes animate2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
  }
}

section .scroll2 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #99e836;
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  width: 100vw;
  border: 2px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7.5rem;
}

section .scroll2 div {
  color: $primary-light;
  font-size: 4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 800;
  animation: animate 40s linear infinite;
}

section .scroll2 div:nth-child(2) {
  animation: animate2 40s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: -20s;
}

section .scroll2 div span {
  margin: 0 2rem;
}

section .scroll.text1 {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

section .scroll2.text2 {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="scroll text1">
    <div>
      <span class="transparent-no"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent-no"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent"> Available for Hire</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="transparent-no"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent-no"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent"> Available for Hire</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll2 text2">
    <div>
      <span class="transparent-no"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent-no"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent"> Available for Hire</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="transparent-no"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent-no"> Available for Hire</span>
      <span class="transparent"> Available for Hire</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[overlapping image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxV55.png)

Comment: No green banner can be seen in your example. Please add more code to the snippet so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I think when you press run code snipper it only runs the HTML. Not sure how I can make it so it runs the CSS as well

Comment: The code runs normally now. It seems to work in here but it doesn't work in my React app.

Comment: Then there is some more css on your react. Please adapt the sniper so we can see the problem.

Comment: The only other code is the whole section being flexed with justify-content and align-items being center. There is nothing else :(

Comment: Or maybe you zoomed into the page causing this overlap? As you see we can only guess, there is not much we can do here. Does it happen on all browser for you? Any information on how to reproduce it is helpful.